# PGF/TikZ and Sans Serif Fonts

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, sans-serif

I have a TikZ/PGF file created directly by a graphing package of the form `\begin{tikzpicture}{dimensions} ... \end{tikzpicture}`.  The file uses `\pgftext[...]{\selectfont{Some text here or \boldmath$math$}}` to render text.

By default, when I include the file in my document, the text is typeset in the default font for my document (Latin Modern Serif).  However, I wish for all of my figures/graphs to be typeset in a sans-serif font (Latin Modern Sans).  How can I go about this?

Ideally, I would like to accomplish this without having to edit the file directly (so just changing the LaTeX around where I include it).

**Update: Minimal Example**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgftext{\selectfont{Hello \boldmath$W \times orld$}}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Anything which can correctly set that piece of text to be sans-serif should do the trick.

Comment: Your graphing package should use `\node` with its `font` option instead of `\pgftext` (in a `tikzpicture` !) and `\selectfont`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here.  One is to make the default font sans-serif so that `\selectfont` selects it.  The other is to get the math to use bold, sans-serif letters.

For the first, `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` works. See “[How do you change the document font in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877597/how-do-you-change-the-document-font-in-latex)” from StackOverflow.

For the second, any new math font versions set up are deselected by `\boldmath`.  In fact, `\boldmath` expands to `\mathversion{bold}`.  So we need to override the font selections for the `bold` math version to choose bold, sans-serif letters.  This is accomplished by `\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{cmbr}{bx}{it}` (There is no Latern Modern math alphabet; [Computer Modern Bright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33168/1402) is a suggested replacement).

Here is the complete working example.  You just need to add two lines to the preamble, and nothing to the automatically-generated part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{cmbr}{bx}{it}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgftext{\selectfont{Hello \boldmath$W \times orld$}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Comment: Works a treat for regular text, but does not touch the math. However, I understand that sans-serif math is a problem in general.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you wanted the math to change font.  Different question.  But the answer can be adapted...whatever commands you can find to do it once, add them before `\sffamily`.

Comment: I've rewritten this answer to better address the user's updated question.

Answer (score 40):

Some more details could have been very helpful. To choose a certain font style for your picture you simply have to give appropriate options to the `tikzpicture` environment.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
% picture contents
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For a global setting you may try `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[font=\sffamily]` in the preamble.

Comment: No luck; I've added a minimal example to my original question so as to be more specific.

Comment: @Freddie: It's better if you include a minimal _working_ example, i.e., a document that can be complied as is, and then say what doesn't work out as you want.

Comment: Great suggestion