# How to typeset some text including math content in sans serif

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

I have a blurb of text in an external macro  `\SomeText`, which I want to typeset in sans serif. However, `\sffamily\SomeText` does not change the math font and `\sffamily\mathsf{\SomeText}` does not work, as I am not in math mode.

So how can I typeset material in sans serif, whether it does or does not include math stuff?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand{\SomeText}{This is some ($words \geq 5$) Text with math stuff in it: $a^2+b^2=c^2$}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item[Roman:] \SomeText
    \item[Sans:] {\sffamily \SomeText \\ (however, the math is still Roman)}

%    LaTeX Error: \mathsf allowed only in math mode
%    \item[AllSans:] {\sffamily\mathsf \SomeText}
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is *all* math stuff to be set in sans-serif, or just one small blurb?

Comment: @Mico: Only small blurbs. I do not want to change the math font globally, I just want sans serif math when `\sffamily` is active.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution in embarrassingly short time after posting the question: The `sansmath` package provides the `\sansmath` command (and several environments) for this purpose.

I am yet curious to know if there is some solution that does not depend on an additional package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\newcommand{\SomeText}{This is some text with math stuff in it. 
    $x>5$, $a^2+b^2=c^2$}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item[Roman:] \SomeText
    \item[Sans:] {\sffamily \SomeText \\ However, the math is still Roman.}
    \item[AllSans:] {\sffamily\sansmath \SomeText}
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest you consider using the `sansmath` package! :-)

Comment: This solution does not work well because, for me, it replaces characters: . (dot) becomes ( (parenthesis) and comma a "plus minus" symbol.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [Make mathfont respect the surrounding family](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33165/make-mathfont-respect-the-surrounding-family). There you’ll find a solution to change the math alphabet and also to make the normal font switches (like `\sffamily`) change the math font too.

Taken from there:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{sans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{sans}{OT1}{cmtl}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathVersion{boldsans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{boldsans}{OT1}{cmbr}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{boldsans}{OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{boldsans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{boldsans}{OT1}{cmbr}{b}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldsans}{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{boldsans}{OT1}{cmtl}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{boldsans}{OMX}{iwona}{bx}{n}

\newif\IfInSansMode
\let\oldsf\sffamily
\renewcommand*{\sffamily}{\oldsf\mathversion{sans}\InSansModetrue}
\let\oldbf\bfseries
\renewcommand*{\bfseries}{\oldbf\IfInSansMode\mathversion{boldsans}\else\mathversion{bold}\fi\relax}
\let\oldnorm\normalfont
\renewcommand*{\normalfont}{\oldnorm\InSansModefalse\mathversion{normal}}
\let\oldrm\rmfamily
\renewcommand*{\rmfamily}{\oldrm\InSansModefalse\mathversion{normal}}

\usepackage[textwidth=9cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Inline-$m\alpha \tau h$}
Normal: A $Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\sffamily Sans: A $Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\bfseries Bold-Sans: A $ Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\normalfont Normal: A $ Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\bfseries  Bold: A $ Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\normalfont Normal: A $ Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\section{Display-$\mu\alpha\tau\eta$}
Text in roman family
\begin{equation}
     \sqrt{(a_1+a_2+\gamma)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i + \gamma
\end{equation}

\sffamily
Text in sans family
\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{(a_1+a_2+\gamma)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i + \gamma
\end{equation}

\sffamily\bfseries
Text in sans family, bold version
\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{(a_1+a_2+\gamma)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i + \gamma
\end{equation}

\rmfamily\bfseries
Text in roman family, bold version
\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{(a_1+a_2+\gamma)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i + \gamma
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Tobi. For some reasons I did not find this question, which comes close to an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

An addition to @Tobi's excellent answer, if you need to use helvetica for the Sans serif fonts:

```
\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{OT1}{cmsmf}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{cmssm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{sans}{OMS}{cmsssy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{sans}{OT1}{cmssm}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{sans}{OT1}{cmsssy}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{sans}{OT1}{cmssex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{cmssex}{m}{n}
```

(taken from `sansmathfonts.sty` from the `sansmathfonts` package).
This then blends in with text that is typesetted with `\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\mdseries` (remember to still use `\sffamily` for the maths)

Example:

[image]