# The right way to get sans-serif math?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

I notice that `beamer` has everything in sans-serif by default, including math. In a regular `article`, simply using `\sffamily` doesn't cause math to be set in sans-serif. Using `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` doesn't work and the [`sansmath` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41497/how-to-typeset-some-text-including-math-content-in-sans-serif) sort of works, but seems to produce varying results with respect to whether letters are italic or not (e.g., in `beamer` `\Gamma` is not italicized, but with `sansmath` it is.)

Is there one "right" way to do this?

Edit: another problem is that `\sansmath` seems to turn `\beta` into "ﬁ".

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24035/9075

Answer (score 19):

There are not many real sans serif math fonts. You can try

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
```

that has math symbol fonts, except for the "large symbols". Perhaps decent results can be obtained by loading the Iwona font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
\[
abc+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{k}\sqrt{2}f(x)\,dx
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach could be with the Arev fonts; changing the preamble above into

```
\usepackage{arevtext,arevmath}
```

you'd get the following

[image]

You find an extensive description of (free) math fonts at this address

http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/en/survey.pdf

Comment: Is it possible to switch to `cmbright` or some other font for a certain portion of the document and then switch back?

Comment: See this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33165/make-mathfont-respect-the-surrounding-family

Comment: That solution is helpful, but when I try it the uppercase Greek letters are not sans-serif... any ideas why?

Comment: This happens when using `mathpazo` only.

Comment: The survey by Stephen Hartke is a bit dated. There is a more extensive survey by Günter Milde (2008, 2010)  http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/Matheschriften/matheschriften.xhtml (Freie Mathematikschriften für LaTeX). In german, though (but see the links at the bottom of the document).

Comment: Any otf sans-serif math fonts You know of?

Comment: @Adobe No, there's none at the moment.

Comment: @egreg: I found [LucidaBrightMathOT](http://tug.org/store/lucida/opentype.html), but it cost a lot of money: 90 pounds, or something like that.

Comment: @Adobe It's not sans serif.

Answer (score 6):

For me (with font set to `\usepackage{helvet}`), the packages  [`mathastext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) and [`isomath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/isomath) did the job to get a consistent appearance (text in mathmode in same style as default text):

```
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
% 'isomath' sets upper case greek letters italic in accordance with 
% the International Standard ISO 80000-2
\usepackage{isomath}
```