# How to switch easily between normal font and sans-serif font for maths?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

I would like to switch easily to sans-serif font, even for the mathematical symbols. Is it possible?

So far is what I have tried :

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mySfFamily{\fontfamily{cmbr}\selectfont\sffamily}
\def\N{\mathbf{N}}
\def\R{\mathbf{R}}
\def\Q{\mathbf{Q}}
\def\Z{\mathbf{Z}}
\def\C{\mathbf{C}}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\mySfFamily
This should be sans-serif : $\R, \Q, \N, \Z, \C$ are sets.
\endgroup

\bigskip

This should be serif : $\R, \Q, \N, \Z, \C$ are sets.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But as you see, it doesn't work for maths. I have chosen the font `\fontfamily{cmbr}` because of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77934/8323).

Comment: Since you are using only boldface letters in math mode you can use `\def\N{\textbf{\textsf{N}}}`

Comment: @Sigur : I also use $x\in\R$ and I want to switch easily between serif and sans-serif mode.

Comment: The style of math fonts usually carries information (such as bold for vectors, italic for scalar variable, etc).  As a reader, I would be confused if you wrote `$x\in\R$` where the `R` was serif and then later read `$x\in\R$` where the `R` was san-serif.  It would make me think the author had two different (though possibly related) sets in mind.

Comment: I see your point of view (even though I don't agree : if the context is non-serif, I will understand that $\R$ sans serif denotes the same object as a usual $\R$). Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: What about using \mathsf{} inside the math environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `sansmath` package provides a command (`\sansmath`) and environment (`sansmath`) for exactly this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\def\mySfFamily{\fontfamily{cmbr}\selectfont\sffamily\sansmath}
\def\N{\mathbf{N}}
\def\R{\mathbf{R}}
\def\Q{\mathbf{Q}}
\def\Z{\mathbf{Z}}
\def\C{\mathbf{C}}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\mySfFamily
This should be sans-serif : $\R, \Q, \N, \Z, \C$ are sets.
\endgroup

\bigskip

This should be serif : $\R, \Q, \N, \Z, \C$ are sets.

\end{document}
```

[image]

To apply this "automagically", I would hack it into the `\sffamily` and `\rmmfamily` commands. (I prefer `\appto` from the `etoolbox` package for this, but one could as well use the usual `\let\OLDmacro\macro` and `\renewcommand\macro{\OLDmacro <extension>}` idiom.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmath,etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}

\appto{\sffamily}{\sansmath}
\appto{\rmfamily}{\unsansmath}


\def\N{\mathbf{N}}
\def\R{\mathbf{R}}
\def\Q{\mathbf{Q}}
\def\Z{\mathbf{Z}}
\def\C{\mathbf{C}}


\begin{document}


\sffamily

This should be sans-serif : $\R, \Q, \N, \Z, \C$ are sets.

\rmfamily

This should be serif : $\R, \Q, \N, \Z, \C$ are sets.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Colas: Is using `sansmath` an option for you or is anything missing from this solution?

Answer (score 8):

Some time ago I asked nearly the [same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33165/make-mathfont-respect-the-surrounding-family), the answer was to define a new math alphabet and hack it into the definition of `\sffamily`. So I’d suggest to close this question as duplicate but it can’ be done until the bounty is closed.

---

This is the code a build upon the answer of egreg.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{sans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{sans}{OT1}{cmtl}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathVersion{boldsans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{boldsans}{OT1}{cmbr}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{boldsans}{OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{boldsans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{boldsans}{OT1}{cmbr}{b}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldsans}{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{boldsans}{OT1}{cmtl}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{boldsans}{OMX}{iwona}{bx}{n}

\newif\IfInSansMode
\let\oldsf\sffamily
\renewcommand*{\sffamily}{\oldsf\mathversion{sans}\InSansModetrue}
\let\oldmd\mdseries
\renewcommand*{\mdseries}{\oldmd\IfInSansMode\mathversion{sans}\fi\relax}
\let\oldbf\bfseries
\renewcommand*{\bfseries}{\oldbf\IfInSansMode\mathversion{boldsans}\else%
   \mathversion{bold}\fi\relax}
\let\oldnorm\normalfont
\renewcommand*{\normalfont}{\oldnorm\InSansModefalse\mathversion{normal}}
\let\oldrm\rmfamily
\renewcommand*{\rmfamily}{\oldrm\InSansModefalse\mathversion{normal}}

\usepackage[textwidth=9cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Inline-$m\alpha \tau h$}
Normal: A $Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\sffamily Sans: A $Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\bfseries Bold-Sans: A $ Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\normalfont Normal: A $ Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\bfseries  Bold: A $ Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\normalfont Normal: A $ Ax\alpha+\chi b$

\section{Display-$\mu\alpha\tau\eta$}
Text in roman family
\begin{equation}
     \sqrt{(a_1+a_2+\gamma)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i + \gamma
\end{equation}

\sffamily
Text in sans family
\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{(a_1+a_2+\gamma)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i + \gamma
\end{equation}

\sffamily\bfseries
Text in sans family, bold version
\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{(a_1+a_2+\gamma)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i + \gamma
\end{equation}

\rmfamily\bfseries
Text in roman family, bold version
\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{(a_1+a_2+\gamma)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i + \gamma
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 6):

For comparison, this is how one can switch from sans to serif math and back in ConTeXt.

```
\def\N{{\bf N}}
\def\R{{\bf R}}
\def\Q{{\bf Q}}
\def\Z{{\bf Z}}
\def\C{{\bf C}}

\startbuffer
Some random text: $\R, \Q, \N, \Z, \C$ are sets.
\stopbuffer

% To format the examples
\setuphead[subject][style=bold, after=]

\starttext

\subject{Default} \getbuffer

\subject{Sans math}

\switchtobodyfont[ss] 
\appendtoks \ss \to \everymathematics
\getbuffer

\subject{Serif math}
\switchtobodyfont[rm]
\appendtoks \rm \to \everymathematics
\getbuffer


\stoptext
```

[image]

You can also use group `{...}` to limit the effect of font changes.

Answer (score 0):

With `unicode-math`, you can declare a new math version as

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont[version=sans]{Fira Math}
```

You can then switch to it with `\mathversion{sans}`.  If you want, you can define commands corresponding to `\boldmath` and `\boldsymbol`.

If you also want a bold sans-serif version, there is no OpenType math font that works out of the box.  As of June 2020, the only sans-serif math font is Fira Math, but the only bold math fonts are XITS, Libertinus and Minion.  Furthermore, `range=` and `version=` do not work together, so you cannot yet load a math version that mixes Libertinus Math Bold with the letters from Libertinus Serif Bold (Italic) or the `sf` alphabets from Libertinus Math.

For the time being, you can apply FakeBold to Fira Math:

```
 \setmathfont[version=boldsans, FakeBold=1.2]{Fira Math}
```

You could then change the formatting of headings to `\sffamily\bfseries\mathversion{boldsans}` to get bold sans-serif math symbols.