# Switch between sans and sans-serif math with MyriadPro and MinionPro

Tags: math-mode, sans-serif, minionpro

I have a document using MinionPro as serif and MyriadPro as sans-serif font families. Math is set by default with the serif font but for captions I like to switch to the sans-serif font. A minimal working example would be:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MyriadPro}
\usepackage[onlysansmath]{mdsymbol}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily
This should be sans-serif, but the math isn't: $E=\hbar\omega$}

This should be sans: $E=\hbar\omega$
\end{document}
```

However, I can get math with MyriadPro if I use the option `\usepackage[math]{MyriadPro}` and using the `mdsymbol` package. Then however, I have no serif math any more... How can I get it to work properly? I tried also to use sansmath but that didn't work. I also looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139012/how-to-switch-easily-between-normal-font-and-sans-serif-font-for-maths) but I cannot get it to work with my choice of fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware of `sansmath` option of `MyriadPro`?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[sansmath]{MyriadPro}
% \usepackage[onlysansmath]{mdsymbol}
% \usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\mathversion{sans}% <=====
This should be sans-serif, but the math isn't: $E=\hbar\omega$}

This should be sans: $E=\hbar\omega$
\end{document}
```