# How to draw multi-blocks block diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, block

I am trying to draw this block diagram
[image]

I am a beginner and I started with this code

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Controller};
    \node [block, right of=controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:D},
    node distance=3cm] (system) {System};
    
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
    \node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {Measurements};
    
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);
    \draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
    \draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
    node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

which results in

[image]

Kindly help me out here. I need to understand this multi sumer block diagram. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Seems like you found this code somewhere and it's not very recent. First, you should not use `tikzstyle` but `tikzset` instead. Then, you didn't post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which forces members to complete your code in order to help you. Finally, what is your precise question? Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: An example of complex control scheme you can find on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395589/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I like to use [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/) to quick draw my diagrams in TikZ, my style converged to defining nodes previously in a `scope` and then another `scope` to all connections.

As a control Eng. myself, I have already created my own styles with `tikzset` and I reuse them as often as I can. So please, don't bother with my custom styles: `addCross`, `mySimpleArrow` and `myBlockOpacity`. The main tip I can give is to create flexible commands (with args) and define a default style. That's a huge improvement from the basic usage.

Notice I didn't displaced to labels exactly where your example presents; I used my `addCross`, you may change it to display the symbols in other positions, or just use a circle and manually displace the symbols. I also didn't change any font since I don't know which one you would like to use. You may check fonts [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169521/typography-and-style-good-choices-for-font-styles-in-tikz-or-pgfplots-graphics).

To give a good example of how some parameters interacts, I let colors `red`  and `purple` in the code. Just change them as you need.

Same is true for commands `minimum height` and `minimum width`. Change them to better fit your document.

To start and finish arrows side by side, I used a technique with`[yshift=<measure>]` provided by [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57285/multiple-arrows-between-nodes).

*Edit note*: I corrected `e_2` to `u_0` after the `Non-linear` block. My mistake while copying the diagram.

The MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{addCross/.style n args={6}{
    minimum size={#5 mm}, %minimum height=10mm,
    path picture={
      \draw[#6]
      (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
      (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.south)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$) {#1};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.west)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$)  {#2};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.north)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$) {#3};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.east)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$)  {#4};
    }
  },
  addCross/.default={}{}{}{}{10}{}
}
\tikzset{mySimpleArrow/.style n args={2}{
    >={latex[#1]},
    every path/.style={draw=#2}
  },
  mySimpleArrow/.default={black}{black}
}
\tikzset{myBlockOpacity/.style n args={2}{
    every node/.style={rectangle,draw,
      minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,
      text=black,
      fill opacity=#1, text opacity=#2}
  },
  myBlockOpacity/.default={0.4}{1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
  \begin{scope}[blue]
    \node[circle,draw,addCross={$-$}{$+$}{}{}{10}{red}] (S1) at (-2,2) {};
    \node[circle,draw,addCross={$-$}{$+$}{}{}{10}{blue}] (S2) at (-0.5,1) {};
    \node[circle,draw,addCross={$-$}{$+$}{}{}{10}{purple}] (S3) at (5.5,1.5) {};
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}[myBlockOpacity, rounded corners, align=center]
    \node[fill=orange, minimum height=80pt, minimum width=60pt] (T) at (-5.5,1.5) 
    {Transient \\Profile \\Generator};
    \node[fill=blue] (P) at (10.5,1.5) {Plant};
    \node[fill=green, minimum height=80pt] (N) at (2.5,1.5)
    {Non-linear \\ State Error \\Feedback};
    \node[fill=yellow, minimum height=80pt] (E) at (7,-2)
    {Extended \\ State \\Observer};
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}[blue,mySimpleArrow={blue}{blue}]
    \path[->] (-7.5,1.5) node[above]{$r$} -- (T);
    
    \path[->] ([yshift=5mm] T.east) -- (S1) node[above, midway]{$r_1$};
    \path[->] ([yshift=-5mm] T.east) -- (S2) node[above, midway]{$r_2$};
    
    \path[->] (S1) -- ([yshift=5mm] N.west) node[midway, above] {$e_1$};
    \path[->] (S2) -- ([yshift=-5mm] N.west) node[midway, above] {$e_2$};
    
    \path[->] (N) -- (S3) node[midway, below] {$u_0$};
    \path[->] (S3) -- ++(3,0) coordinate(u) -- (P);
    \path[->] (u) |- ([yshift=10pt]E.east) node[above right, midway]{$u$};
    
    \path[->] (P) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(y) |- ([yshift=-10pt]E.east);
    \path[->] (y) -- ++(1,0) node[above]{$y$};
    
    \path[->,red] ([yshift=-20pt] E.west) -| (S1) node[above right, midway]{$z_1$};
    \path[->] (E) -| (S2) node[above right, midway]{$z_2$};
    \path[->,purple] ([yshift=20pt] E.west) -| (S3) node[above right, midway]{$z_3$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for very precise explanation and help! I really appreciate it.