# Downloaded Font does not show on Typeset in TexShop

Tags: fonts

I've downloaded and installed the font Arial for TexShop from getnonfreefonts. 
It worked the first time around and after I typeset, it has gone back to the default font. How can I get it back to Arial?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = british]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{array}                                                                       
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-19pt}{0pt}
\usepackage[square, sort, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tocfill}{\cleaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern\@dotsep mu . \mkern\@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[3cm][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \tocfill}}
\newenvironment{abbreviations}{\begin{list}{}{\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrlabel}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{3cm}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
                                              \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}{\end{list}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: You are loading four font packages: `lmodern`, `uarial`,  `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.  The `newtxtext` package (Times) is overriding the `uarial` package. If you want the whole document (excluding math) to be in Arial, then you need to add `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` and remove the other font packages.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know the newtxtext was the one causing the problem.

Comment: This is only one of many problems with your preamble, all of which are potential causes of trouble. Don't load packages more than once. Don't load packages you don't need. Don't load packages whose use you have no idea about. `hyperref` must be loaded last, with a few specific exceptions (most notably `cleveref`). You are loading it too early. `xcolor` already loads `color`. `tikz` loads `xcolor` and `graphicx`. Do you really need `filecontents`? And so on ....

Comment: This is my first time using latex so I'm working on a template given by my friend. But thanks for the suggestion. I'm still getting to grips with it and I'll keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

Your document loads *four* font packages: `lmodern`, `uarial`, `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. The `newtxtext` package is overriding your `uarial` settings.  So you need to remove the packages you don't need. If you want the entire document (excluding math) to be in Arial, then do the following:

```
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

If you want sans serif math support too, you will need to do something different. See:

- [The right way to get sans-serif math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77932/2693)

Comment: And the rest ... ;)