# Sections and subsections in Latin Modern

Tags: fonts

I'm using pdfTeX in MikTeX and have included

```
\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont
```

in my preamble to make all fonts look like Latin Modern. However, this does not seem to apply to the font used in section and subsection names, and neither does the math typography change. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also related: [The right way to get sans-serif math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77932/the-right-way-to-get-sans-serif-math)

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. `\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont` is just the normal definition of `\sffamily` and selects computer modern sans serif not latin modern. (latin modern sans serif would be `lmss`)

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? If you are using a koma class, maybe `\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrbook}` could help.

Comment: \documentclass[dutch,a4paper,twoside]{book}