# Typeset WHOLE document in sans-serif, Including Math Mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

The reigning answer for the *[Simplest way to typeset entire document in sans serif (Helvetica)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/simplest-way-to-typeset-entire-document-in-sans-serif-helvetica)* completely disregards math-mode.  This might be preferred when all math equations are set display style, but a matching font is a must for in-line equations.

My current MWE (based on the one given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2097/47522)) only gives the text-mode items in sans, but any math remains in serif style (in-line, numerical-only equations look particularly hideous).

How can I set math in sans-serif as well?

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Text looks particularly bad when you have $123,400$ number-only equations in-line.

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to typeset some text including math content in sans serif](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41497/5764)

Comment: @Werner And as prompted by the answer there, is there a way to do this without a package?  Any equivalent of `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}` for math mode?

Comment: @cslstr: No there is no one-liner to get sans serif math. Math is complicated, it involves a lot of fonts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer, as I have pieced together, appears here on one page, for posterity.

The package [`sansmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sansmath) ...

> ...is designed to offer sans-serif mathematics in the absence of proper
>   sans maths fonts. After `\usepackage{sansmath}`, a new “math version”
>   sans is deﬁned, together with a command `\sansmath`, which behaves as
>   `\boldmath` does.  *-from the documentation*

So the MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sansmath} % Enables turning on sans-serif math mode, and using other environments
\sansmath % Enable sans-serif math for rest of document

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Text looks particularly bad when you have $123,400$ number-only equations in-line.

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: example sans math]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` instead of `LaTeX` to compile your document,

and use `FiraSans`, `Fira Math` and `FiraMono` for sans serif text, math mode, and typewriter font, respectively (the font and its typesetting are so beautiful, they make my mouth water):

[image: Fira fonts example]

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}        % Change default sans serif (sf) font to FiraSans
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}   % Text in math mode will also be sans serif
\setmathfont{Fira Math}                 % Change default math font to FiraMath
\usepackage{FiraMono}                   % Change default typewriter (tt) font to FiraMono
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set sans serif font as default

\usepackage[english]{babel}             % For writing english in blindtext
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}            % Placeholder text

% Narrow page edges, so that we can have more text
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}                       % Remove page numbers


\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper    % Placeholder text

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, if you insist on using `LaTeX` compiler, or have to use the `helvet` font:

Using `arev`, or `arev` with `helvet` is another solution (note that `arev` has some typesetting issues with subscripts, [see this question for details](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268121/whats-wrong-with-arevs-subscript-placement)).

[image: arev + helvet]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set sans serif font as default

\usepackage[english]{babel}   % For writing english in blindtext
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}  % Placeholder text

% Narrow page edges, so that we can have more text
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty} % Remove page numbers


\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper  % Placeholder text

\end{document}
```

Comment: The package `unicode-math` doesn't seem to be compatible with the AMS packages or `mathtools`, which I use.

Comment: No, `unicode-math` isn't compatible with `mathtools`. But, for example, `\coloneqq` from `mathtools` is implemented as `\coloneq` in `unicode-math`.