# How to combine another sans-serif math font with helvet for text?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, sans-serif

The existing question [Typeset WHOLE document in sans-serif, Including Math Mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174021/typeset-whole-document-in-sans-serif-including-math-mode) uses the `sansmath` package to use `helvet` glyphs also in math-mode. But being not designed for use in math mode, the results don't look convincing.

According to this [survey of free math fonts](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/Matheschriften/matheschriften.xhtml#sans-serif-grotesk), it seems to be possible to use another font (mentioned are [`cmbright`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cmbright) and [`lxfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lxfonts) as similar) for math-mode in combination with `helvet` for text-mode. However, I cannot find pointers on how to setup the document appropriately. (How) can it be done?

The obligatory MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{helvet} % for text-mode
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% \usepackage{cmbright} % one of these for...
% \usepackage{lxfonts}  % math-mode only

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update, use `sansmathfonts` instead of `sansmath`

A year later, I finally found a combination of text and math font for a `helvet`-based document. Source: [Egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268123/30821) to my question about [arev's strange placement of subscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268121/30821).

#### Result

> [image: helvet text with sansmathfonts math blindmathpaper]

#### New code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
%\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{beramono} % for code listings
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

---

### Old (`helvet` + `arev`)

I should have read the [survey link](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/Matheschriften/matheschriften.xhtml#sans-serif-grotesk) I provided more carefully. The author was so nice to not only provide the comparison as `pdf`, but also as `tex` for each font combination. He explains how to combine the math font of *Arev* with text font of *Heros*, which is a *Helvetica* clone. So with a slight change from `tgheros` to `helvet`, my working example becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arev} % sans-serif math font
\usepackage{helvet} % sans-serif text font
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is similar, but your "1" does not look like rendered using Helvetica or Liberation Sans font in either implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The [manual of `sansmath`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sansmath/sansmath.pdf) states the following:

> The actual sans fonts are OT1 encodings of those indicated by the
>   meaning of \sfdefault WHEN THE PACKAGE WAS LOADED, not the meaning at
>   each maths environment!

We can exploit this fact by first loading the desired math font, then `sansmath`, and finally `helvet` for the text font. This is straightforward when `cmbright` is used for maths:

[image: Sample with Helvetica text and CM Bright maths]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Some other technique would be needed for `lxfonts` which acts at the end of the preamble, overriding earlier font settings (`helvet`).