# Setting up a Sans Serif Document Including Math (in 2017, using pdftex)

Tags: math-mode, fonts, pdftex, sans-serif

I try to set up an **entire document using sans serif fonts including math**. At the moment I would like to use `pdftex`.

I searched the relevant questions and answers -- this is what I found:

- [based on [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)] [How to combine another sans-serif math font with helvet for text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197813) (**2014**, August)
- [[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)] [What's wrong with arev's subscript placement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268121) (**2015**, September)
- [[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) again] [The right way to get sans-serif math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77932) (**2016**, October)
- [[mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) and others] [How to typeset some text including math content in sans serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41497) (**2012**, Januar)
- [Typeset WHOLE document in sans-serif, Including Math Mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174021) (**2014**, April)

### `kpfonts` Package

This is an **edit** from 2017-06-09. I found `kpfonts` by accident and they seem to be promising.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

% https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts
% Complex package -- read the documentation!
\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
Text
$\displaystyle
abc+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{k}\sqrt{2}f(x)\,\text{d}x
$
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

### `cmbright` Package

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Text
$\displaystyle
abc+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{k}\sqrt{2}f(x)\,\text{d}x
$
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

### `arevtext` and `arevmath` (or simply `arev`) Package

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{arev}
% Suggested from Mico
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Text
$\displaystyle
abc+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{k}\sqrt{2}f(x)\,\text{d}x
$
Text
\end{document}
```

*Without `\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}`*
[image]

*With `\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}`*
[image]

### `sansmathfonts` and `helvet` Package

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Text
$\displaystyle
abc+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{k}\sqrt{2}f(x)\,\text{d}x
$
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

### `newtxsf` Package

The following code is taken from the [newtxsf](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtxsf/) documentation and adjusted to the code examples above.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[sfdefault,scaled=.85]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}% inconsolata typewriter
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxsf}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Text
$\displaystyle
abc+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{k}\sqrt{2}f(x)\,\text{d}x
$
Text
\end{document}
```

I have trouble running the code since I get an error in the file `miktex-makemf.log`. I already refreshed the FNDB (MiKTeX). The **error** is **not part of the question** though.

Maybe someone can add the output of the code for me.

[image]

> 2017-03-21 02:02:13,987+0100 FATAL miktex-makemf - The txsys source
>   file could not be found.

After following the comment of [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) (running `upmap` on the command window of Windows), the error is gone!

[image]

### `sansmath` and `helvet` Package

`sansmath` doesn't seem to be an active package (this is an assumption -- nothing more). I only found **2003-08-13, version 1.0** on CTAN.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sansmath} 
\sansmath 

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Text
$\displaystyle
abc+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{k}\sqrt{2}f(x)\,\text{d}x
$
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

### More Packages That Seem Related

- [stix](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stix) (v1.1.2-latex from 2015/04/17)

### Other Related Information

- http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/en/survey.pdf (found in one of egreg's answers, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77932); **2006**, May).
- http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/Matheschriften/matheschriften.xhtml (**2008**, August; only in German, was mentioned in one of the comments of egreg's [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77932))

### Actual Questions

1. **What is the nowadays recommended way to set up a complete sans serif document?** I aim for a solution that is considered state-of-the-art with a (if possible) complete set of symbols and font versions (Small Caps and do on).
2. What do font packages like `sansmathfonts` do? Do they "just" make already existing fonts (or single characters / symbols) available in a convenient package (so it's "luck" if everything fits together) or did the authors create new fonts?

### Background -- Why Do I Want This

I one of the comments (Mico) I was asked to explain what I want do to with the sans serif fonts.

- I help a friend which just started to be a teacher.
- If we create documents that are used on any kind of projectors, then the serif fonts sometimes cause readability problems.
- With documents I mean, e. g. beamer presentations or standalone diagrams.
- I attached one of the standalone diagrams below. The pictures have the same resolution.
- So it's *not* for a book, article or paper.

---

*Standard Solution with Serif Fonts (no font package loaded -- I assume Computer Modern then)*
[image]

---

*Sans Serif Version -- Using the `avec` Package Approach from Above and Recommended by Mico*
[image]

Comment: Sans serif fonts do not usually feature either small-caps or true italics. Hence a `complete` solution really should not requite small-caps. Traditionally and standardly, small-caps are serifs.

Comment: Why do you assume that a package last updated in 2003 is not active? Is it marked unmaintained? Many packages don't need updating and authors do not keep deluging the CTAN team with uploads just to put shiny new dates on their packages. At least, they shouldn't and I can't think why anybody would. I certainly don't.

Comment: Did you read the commentary on `sansmath.sty`. It tells you what it does, what it doesn't do and what you might be better doing instead of using it.

Comment: Are you fixed to `pdflatex` or is a transition to e.g. `xelatex` possible?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any development available.

Comment: The miktex error probably means that you should run `updmap` on a command (the document compiles fine for me).

Comment: @TeXnician I personally will use `pdflatex` but if you can provide an alternative for others. And now I see that I should include this in the question -- thanks for asking.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks -- that did the trick. I updated the question.

Comment: @cfr **a)** About `sansmath` -- I just assumed it. And I didn't intend to be negative about it. If the assumption is wrong -- good. **b)** I read the documentation of `sansmathfonts` and I understood that it "just" uses existing "stuff". Unlike some of you guys I cannot read style files like plain text :). **c)** The whole font stuff is still very confusing for me. Normally I just use `lmodern` and I was happy so far. Right now I am helping a math and physics teacher (who just started as a teacher) setting up LaTeX and for some kind of documents, the sans serif font are helpful.

Comment: @egreg Thanks -- so you mean that the examples I collected are "all" there is. Which solution would you use?

Comment: It would help if you stated the purpose(s) or reason(s) for wishing to use sans-serif math and text. E.g., is it a personal preference for sans-serif over serif glyphs, is it a requirement of some publishing house, is it because you're preparing a `beamer` presentation and don't like the default (Computer Modern sans) sans serif choice, or still something else? Just as there will never be an "overall best" serif font, there will never be an "overall best" sans-serif font...

Comment: @Mico Good point. I added some information. I am offline now (at least not on a computer, only mobile).

Comment: I didn't mean to read the code of the style file. It includes a lot of commented commentary. (This may be the same as the documentation - I didn't check. For example, it discusses combining with or substituting Euler, notes limitations etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the document is going to take the form of a `beamer` presentation, I recommend you -- or the colleague you're helping to get started -- do two things:

- issue the instruction `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` in the preamble, and
- load the `arev` package, which loads the `arevtext` and `arevmath` packages.

In my experience, the `arev` text and math fonts are both a bit darker and more widely spaced than the corresponding CM Sans fonts. I consider both of these features to be significant pluses for the purpose of writing a `beamer`-based presentation. For beginners in the business of giving presentations, a perennial and near-fatal tempatation is to try to cram too much material into any given slide. A font that's slightly more generously spaced and therefore makes it more difficult to cram too much material into a slide is highly advantageous in this regard. :-)

Another thing I like about the `arev` math fonts -- however, this is clearly just a personal preference -- is that quite a few of the math-mode alphabetic glyphs actually look "italic" rather than just "slanted". This is quite apparent if one compares `\textit{x}` (purely slanted) with `$x$` (more "italic", not just slanted). Other glyphs that have this distinctly "italic" look in math mode are `a`, `f`, `i`, `l`, `u`, `v`, and `w`. To repeat what I stated before, though: This is clearly just a personal preference; your preferences may very well be rather different.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\displaystyle abc + \sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^k \sqrt{2} f(x)\,\text{d}x$

\medskip\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll}
text-mode: & \emph{bcdeghjkmnopqrstyz} & \emph{afiluvwx} \\
math-mode: & $bcdeghjkmnopqrstyz$      & $afiluvwx$
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good point! And it has a good readability on screens and so on. Thanks. I wait till tonight to accept the answer -- maybe there are more options.

Comment: I now use the recommendation in the diagram example above (picture is updated). Your points are clearly visible. The `avec` package doesn't seem to have a lot of documentation. I only found http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/arev/doc/fonts/arev/arevdoc.pdf.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Also, keep in mind that it's permissible to provide the instruction `\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}` after `\usepackage{arev}`, should you prefer the summation and integral symbols of the `iwona` font, even if all other glyphs come from  `arev`.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the example in the question with a comparison, accordingly.

Comment: I just saw the `cabin` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cabin) in a comment (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364060). It looks interesting. Do you think that I should add it as an example in the question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Thanks. As far as I can tell, `cabin` is a pure text-mode font; no math support at all. If the `beamer` document doesn't involve any math at all, sure -- go ahead and consider using `cabin`. Do note that it's quite compressed -- esp. when compared with `arev`. Compressed sans-serif may be a virtue (or a necessity...) in some documents, but in a `beamer` document my view is that compressed fonts should be avoided if you have any regard for the folks in the audience...

Comment: Please allow me an additional question, no problem if that's too much to ask (I am amazed what effort some people provide here). Is the `mathdesign` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign) something that should be added into the collection in my question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - I don't think it would *hurt* -- :-) -- to mention the `mathdesign` package and some of its principal options (`utopia`, `garamond`, and `charter`). To keep things focused on the subject of documents that broadly fall into the category of beamer-type presentations, you may want to limit the discussion to just the sans-serif font possibilities. Otherwise, your already-long answer might easily become twice as long... :-)

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments: This is just for reference and not a real solution for the `pdflatex`-specific question. The following solution is `xelatex`-only, because it uses [`mathspec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathspec), which lets you use any system-wide installed font and adjust many aspects of the math font (including specific fonts for `\mathbb`, `\mathcal`, `\mathfrak` etc. and the selection according to character groups "Latin", "Greek", "Digits").

This is a very simple way to get a sans-only document, since you can use multiple fonts to cover the whole unicode area as needed (most sans fonts miss the calligraphic or fraktur characters). In the following example I use the "Linux Biolinum" font.

[image: biolinum]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Linux Biolinum G}
\setallsansfonts{Linux Biolinum G}
\setallmonofonts{Linux Biolinum G}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[ItalicFont=Linux Biolinum G Italic,%
    BoldFont=Linux Biolinum G Bold]{Linux Biolinum G}%

\begin{document}

This is a test.

Text
\(\displaystyle
abc+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{k}\sqrt{2} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\)
Text\\

\(\alpha + \mathcal{X}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use xelatex, can I just use the same code as in pdftex? (except of the font stuff)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, you can, except that you should remove the packages `inputenc` (as `utf8` is expected) and `fontenc` (as it automatically uses open-type).

Comment: A similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374250/are-there-opentype-sans-math-fonts-under-development) has recently evolved : the recent availability ot two Sans Math fonts essentially solves the problem for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTex (as well as OpenType-enabled software such as LibreOffice, by the way). Unless you are dead set to use pdfLaTeX, these solutions seem to be both easier, more consistent and more æsthetically pleasing than the current kludges...