# Change the sans serif font for a document

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I am currently using the package `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}` to produce fonts for the main text in a document, as well as equations in mathematics mode. I would like to change to sans serif font from that used with this package to Avant Garde, but keeping the fonts used for everything else the same. How can I go about this?

Comment: In ny opinion, `cabin`  fits better utopia.

Comment: Oh right, I haven't seen that one before

Comment: How would I implement it with utopia?

Comment: `\usepackage{cabin}` makes it the default sans-serif font.

Comment: I've added that line but if I use \sffamily then that text does not appear to be in sans serif

Comment: Which distribution do you have?

Comment: Do you mean what order they are in? It's \usepackage{cabin} 
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

Comment: No. The question is: are you under TeX Live or MiKTeX?

Comment: I'm using TeX live

Comment: Did you run `updmap -sys`?