# everymath and set font for math

Tags: math-mode

I’m trying to have all the math components of my table in `\mathsf` and `\mathbf`. I thought I’d use `\everymath` to set the `\scriptscriptstyle`, `\mathbf` and `\mathsf`, but I’m not able to figure it out.

```
\boldmath
\everymath{\scriptscriptstyle\mathsf}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this question is interesting for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33165/4918 (no duplicate)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\mathsf` takes an argument, it doesn't make the following expression sans serif. You can switch to math sans serif, then  get the underlying `\mathgroup` (`\fam`) number and then set that for the entire math expression:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\boldmath
\everymath{\mathsf{\xdef\mysf{\mathgroup\the\mathgroup\relax}}\mysf}

$abc$


\end{document}
```

Comment: that works..thx.. But how can I at the same time apply the scriptscriptstyle?

Comment: oo I forgot that one just put `\scriptscriptstyle` before the last `\mysf`

Comment: Thx a million...

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of trial and error, I've found that the following also seems to work:

```
\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\sf}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\sf}
```