# How to get both usual text as well as all mathematical symbols in slanted?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, slanted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make mathfont respect the surrounding family](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33165/make-mathfont-respect-the-surrounding-family)

I have text in slanted, but I would like to get the math symbols in between also in slanted. (To be precise, with the 'slanted' I'm talking about here I mean `\textsl{...}`.)

So how can I accomplish this?

In fact I would want a command that makes ordinary takes as well as math symbols slanted.

To be concrete: now I have something like

```
\textsl{If} $x^2 > 0$, \textsl{then} $x \neq 0$
```

which I do not entirely like as my mathematical symbols are not in slanted.

But ideally I'd like a command, call it `\allsl` perhaps, so that if I would write

```
 \allsl{If $x^2 > 0$, then $x \neq 0$}
```

then *every* symbol of this line (both letters as well as mathematical symbols) would be in slanted.

The question is thus: how can I define such a command which accomplishes this?

Comment: Do the answers in this related question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33165/8057 .