# Why isn’t math bold when set in bold context, like \textbf{Text $f_i$}?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

Here is my code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
 \begin{document}
 \textbf{\textit{Les caractéristiques $f_i$}}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

My question is: why "fi" isn't in bold ?

Comment: **Please, do not do this.** Bolding math in bold environment is a very bad typographical practice, since bold and non-bold `f` can be (and quite often are) two completely different things. For the same reason, `\sin` stays upright even in theorem body, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also `\boldsymbol` but it does not work so well as the above answers. See MWE below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{\textit{Les caractéristiques $\boldsymbol f_{\!\boldsymbol i}$}}\\
\textbf{\boldmath\textit{Les caractéristiques $f_i$}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bolding math in bold environment is a very bad typographical practice, since bold and non-bold `f` can be (and quite often are) two completely different things. For the same reason, `\sin` stays upright even in theorem body, etc.

Comment: True, true @tohecz. I am just throwing out ideas that I had seen some months aback in code that I borrowed from friend.

Comment: @azetina And I'm just adding a disclaimer to warn people that even though they ask for it, they actually don't want it ;)

Comment: @tohecz Do edit my question and bold the `disclaimer` :-)

Answer (score 19):

The f isn’t bold because it’s set in math mode and in math *f*  and ***f***  can be different things. E.g. ***f***  is a vector and *f*  the length of the vector.

LaTeX has its own treatment for math fonts which can be affected by the user with commands like `\mathbf`. But the math fonts don’t depend on the surrounding text font. You may have a look at [Make mathfont respect the surrounding family](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33165/4918), where you can find settings to get your desired behaviour. An image taken frome there to illustrate the result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 8):

Please post complete documents not just fragments (so this isn't tested) but you want

```
 \begin{document}
 \textbf{\boldmath\textit{Les caractéristiques $f_i$}}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to mention all possibilities, there is also the [`bm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm) package with its `\bm` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\textit{Les caractéristiques $\bm{f_i}$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]