# Combination of Palatino and Arev results in wrong parenthesis in math

Tags: fonts, symbols, math-fonts

Following [Make mathfont respect the surrounding family](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33165/4918) I’m trying to set up my document to use Platino and Arev for math depending on text context too. Unfornutalty it gives me the wrong parenthesis in math mode, when Arev is in use:

[image]

The problem seems to affect only the normal sized parenthesis; brackets and braces work fine, as well as bigger parenthesis.

**How can I set up the right parens?**

*Code:*

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[scaled=1.15]{newpxtext}
\usepackage[varg,scaled=1.15,cmintegrals]{newpxmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage{siunitx}
   \sisetup{detect-all}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fav}

\DeclareMathVersion{arev}

\SetSymbolFont {operators}    {arev} {OT1} {zavm}  {m} {n}
\SetSymbolFont {letters}      {arev} {OML} {zavm}  {m} {it}
\SetSymbolFont {symbols}      {arev} {OMS} {zavm}  {m} {n}
\SetSymbolFont {largesymbols} {arev} {OMX} {mdbch} {m} {n}

\SetMathAlphabet {\mathrm} {arev} {OT1} {zavm} {m} {n}
\SetMathAlphabet {\mathsf} {arev} {OT1} {zavm} {m} {n}
\SetMathAlphabet {\mathit} {arev} {OT1} {zavm} {m} {it}
\SetMathAlphabet {\mathbf} {arev} {OT1} {zavm} {b} {n}
\SetMathAlphabet {\mathtt} {arev} {T1}  {fvm}  {m} {n}

\newif\IfInSansMode
\LetLtxMacro\oldsf\sffamily
\renewcommand*{\sffamily}{\oldsf\mathversion{arev}\InSansModetrue}
\LetLtxMacro\oldrm\rmfamily
\renewcommand*{\rmfamily}{\oldrm\InSansModefalse\mathversion{normal}}

\newcommand{\TestText}{%
   $\{[(a+b)]\} = \left(\frac{c-d}{e+f}\right)$ (Text-Mode)
}

\begin{document}
\TestText

\sffamily
\TestText
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which of the many parenthese is wrong?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think he wants the () in math at the left of the second example to use the same () as text on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

newtxmath redefines the delimiters:

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{lettersA}{125}{largesymbols}{0}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{lettersA}{126}{largesymbols}{1}
```

so your changes in the operator/letter font don't affect them.

You can reset them but only globally as `\DeclareMathDelimiter` can be used only in the preamble. If you want to use the parentheses from the text font, you can try `\SetSymbolFont {operators}    {arev} {T1} {fav}  {m} {n}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[scaled=1.15]{newpxtext}
\usepackage[varg,scaled=1.15,cmintegrals]{newpxmath}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fav}

\DeclareMathVersion{arev}

\SetSymbolFont {operators}    {arev} {OT1} {zavm}  {m} {n}
\SetSymbolFont {letters}      {arev} {OML} {zavm}  {m} {it}
\SetSymbolFont {symbols}      {arev} {OMS} {zavm}  {m} {n}
\SetSymbolFont {largesymbols} {arev} {OMX} {mdbch} {m} {n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{"28}{largesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{largesymbols}{"01}

\begin{document}

\sffamily 
$\bigg ((a+b)$ (Text-mode)

\mathversion{arev}
$\bigg ((a+b)$ (Text-mode)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Adding the two `\DeclareMathDelimiter` commands did the trick – it seems.

Answer (score 2):

The `arev` math fonts use the standard LaTeX math codes, but `newpxmath` changes a few of them.

I acted on the parentheses, you may want to add other codes in a similar fashion. I also used `xpatch` to simplify patching `\rmfamily` and `\sffamily`.

```
\documentclass{book}

% store the necessary standard codes
\edef\latexmathcodelparen{\the\mathcode`(\relax}
\edef\latexdelcodelparen{\the\delcode`(\relax}
\edef\latexmathcoderparen{\the\mathcode`)\relax}
\edef\latexdelcoderparen{\the\delcode`)\relax}

\usepackage[scaled=1.15]{newpxtext}
\usepackage[varg,scaled=1.15,cmintegrals]{newpxmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro,xpatch}

\usepackage{siunitx}
   \sisetup{detect-all}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fav}

% store the codes from newpxmath
\edef\pxmathcodelparen{\the\mathcode`(\relax}
\edef\pxmathcoderparen{\the\mathcode`)\relax}
\edef\pxdelcodelparen{\the\delcode`(\relax}
\edef\pxdelcoderparen{\the\delcode`)\relax}

\DeclareMathVersion{arev}

\SetSymbolFont {operators}    {arev} {OT1} {zavm}  {m} {n}
\SetSymbolFont {letters}      {arev} {OML} {zavm}  {m} {it}
\SetSymbolFont {symbols}      {arev} {OMS} {zavm}  {m} {n}
\SetSymbolFont {largesymbols} {arev} {OMX} {mdbch} {m} {n}

\SetMathAlphabet {\mathsf} {arev} {OT1} {zavm} {m} {n}
\SetMathAlphabet {\mathit} {arev} {OT1} {zavm} {m} {it}
\SetMathAlphabet {\mathbf} {arev} {OT1} {zavm} {b} {n}
\SetMathAlphabet {\mathtt} {arev} {T1}  {fvm}  {m} {n}

\newif\IfInSansMode
\xapptocmd\sffamily{%
  \mathversion{arev}%
  \InSansModetrue
  % restore the standard codes
  \mathcode`(=\latexmathcodelparen
  \mathcode`)=\latexmathcoderparen
  \delcode`(=\latexdelcodelparen
  \delcode`)=\latexdelcoderparen
}{}{}
\xapptocmd\rmfamily{%
  \InSansModefalse
  \mathversion{normal}%
  % restore the newpxmath codes
  \mathcode`(=\pxmathcodelparen
  \mathcode`)=\pxmathcoderparen
  \delcode`(=\pxmathcodelparen
  \delcode`)=\pxmathcoderparen
}{}{}

\newcommand{\TestText}{%
   $\{[(a+b)]\} = \left(\frac{c-d}{e+f}\right)$ (Text-Mode)
}

\begin{document}
\TestText

\sffamily
\TestText
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a check document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arevtext,arevmath}
\begin{document}

$\{[(a+b)]\} = \left(\frac{c-d}{e+f}\right)$ (Text-Mode)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What’s the difference to Ulrikes answer? I mean is on of them more robust or are they just different solutions?

Comment: @Tobi It's quite different. Ulrike is changing the codes also for the normal math version, so the parentheses are different from the usual `newpxmath` ones.

Comment: But the (optical) result seems to be the same, wo which solution should I prefer?

Comment: @Tobi That's up to you. My solution can be generalized also for other characters you need to modify.

Comment: I see … I think I use Ulrikes version since it’s shorter :-)