# How can I do to correct styles in chapter names with equations?

Tags: header-footer, titles

***Edited***

I want to make the name written in mathematical mode match the style title of the section.

The first lines of my code are

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
```

My document has chapters and sections that appear text and formulas together. If I use

```
\section{Properties of $Ti_3SiC_2$}
```

the result is

[image]

in the text and

[image]

in the index.

To try to correct the difference between font styles in both places, the line of code that I used is:

```
\subsection[Properties of \texorpdfstring{$\mathrm{ZrB_2+SiC}$}{TEXT}]{Properties of \texorpdfstring{$\mathbf{ZrB_2+SiC}$}{TEXT}}
```

and the result in the index is

[image]

And in the title of the section is

[image]

It may seem that the styles match, but no. That is, in both cases the letters of Properties and ZrB_2 look different.
Does somebody know anything about this? Now is it better understood?

Pd: I do not want the title of the text and the index to have the same style format. What I intend is that the format of the title with the mathematical expression, and the index with the mathematical expression, be the same.

Comment: you mean `\tableofcontents` by "index" ? You have specified `\mathrm` in one case and `\mathbf`  in the other so naturally they use different fonts?

Comment: Yes I know. What I am referring to is the same style of print. For example, in the title the word Properties seems to have a calligraphy other than ZrB_2. I do not know if I explain.

Comment: the font choice is entirely set up in code that you have not shown so it is very hard to say anything unless you provide an example. It is entirely normal for a section heading to use a bold font from a different font family to the main text, and for tables of contents to be set using the main text font not using the heading font.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. Also, you might want to have  a look into the `mhchem` package that is dedicated to typesetting chemical formulae.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39886/4918.

Comment: @Valveroz: As already mentioned, you might want to use `mhchem`as follows: `\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Properties of \ce{Ti_3SiC_2}}
\section{Properties of \ce{ZrB_2 + SiC}}
\end{document}` [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhmpI.png)

Comment: Great. Thank you. That's just what I was looking for. But I get many ads of this type: `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `\mhchem@cee' on input line 96.` and `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `subscript' on input line 96.`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for the `\boldmath` macro.  In a standard document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{ZrB_2+SiC}$ vs. {\boldmath$\mathrm{ZrB_2+SiC}$}
\end{document}
```

[image: short sample]

A possibility that might work for you to avoid too much extra encoding is to add `\boldmath` to any invocation of `\bfseries`.  This can be done via the internal macro `\g@addto@macro` via

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Properties of $Ti_3SiC_2$}

\section{Beware bold math $\mathbf{x}y\mathrm{z}$}
\end{document}
```

As the second heading shows, this will probably not be acceptable if you mix `\mathbf` and `\mathrm` in your equations.

Answer (score 1):

Use a chemistry package, for instance `chemformula` (or `mhchem`):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{chemformula}


\begin{document}

\section{Properties of \ch{Ti3SiC2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Below a picture showing what you'd get in the table of contents.

[image]

Side notes: the `pdftex` option should not be specified, as packages that need it are able to guess the driver based on the engine used for typesetting. With recent TeX distributions, loading `inputenc` with the `utf8` option is no longer needed (but it makes no harm).

Answer (score 0):

For my case in particular, the solution given by @leandriis is perfectly valid. The only thing is that I have a series of warnings like this one

`Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing \mhchem@cee' on input line 96.` and `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing subscript' on input line 96.`

Someone knows how it can be solved